# How can I redirect the defaul.aspx to another page ( for eg mynew.aspx )using Web.config

Tags: asp.net

How can I redirect the defaul.aspx to another page ( for eg  mynew.aspx ) using Web.config? I wrote my website in MS Visual Studio 2010 (C#)

Comment: do you want to change your default page ? or just want to redirect ?

Comment: I want to change my default page. not redirect

Answer (score 2):

under:

```
<system.webServer>
 <defaultDocument>
  <files>
   <clear \>
    <add value = "mynewdefault.aspx" />
  </files>
```

And close everything else like normal.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using authentication then `defaultUrl` property can be a solution.

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"  defaultUrl="~/Welcome.aspx" />
</authentication>
```

Your new default page is `Welcome.aspx` now.

Comment: I had written what you wrote. let me explain: I have several default.aspx files in different folders. I want to see ~web/default.aspx when I write "www.mywebsite.com" in the address bar. Now when I write www.mywebsite.com nothing is displayed. But when I write manually, www.mywebsite.com/web/default.aspx then useful page is loaded. I want it automatically but how?

Comment: If you deployed your project on Windows Server, then from Internet Information Services, you need to open the properties of your web application. From there, open Documents tab and add new default page. I edited my answer for picture of IIS options / documents.

Comment: I upload my files to host. my website is now live.

Comment: I always use my own server so my answer could be wrong :). For other hosts, there should be option somewhere to select your default page.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you should use default document as suggested in other answers. Still if someone needs to redirect a single page using httpRedirect module here is the configuration they should use.

```
<system.webServer>
  <httpRedirect enabled="true" exactDestination="true" childOnly="true" destination="">
    <clear/>
    <add wildcard="/Default.aspx" destination="MyNew.aspx" />
  </httpRedirect>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: when I wrote above in my web.config file it is written that <system.webServer> has invaild child element.... ?

Comment: httpRedirect module should be installed on your iis. Also this somehow disables debugging with visual studio 2010.

Comment: This should go under <configuration /> element.